# Visual Studio Code - Python - List Index Limit Max 300 - Debugger

Tags: python, list, visual-studio-code

I have a list contains several hundred entries. I think the total size of the list is 3.5 MB.

When debugging an issue I can't seem to view any entry passed 300 and I see this message 'Too large to show contents. Max items to show: 300'

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to find a file named `pydevd_resolver.py` under your Visual Studio Code workspace directory
(you can find it with Bash this command: `find / -name pydevd_resolver.py 2>/dev/null`).

Open the file, and inside it look for a constant definition: `MAX_ITEMS_TO_HANDLE = 300`. You can change this number to whatever you like, but please note this will of course consume more resources, so be careful with this.

Just for the sake of completion, I paste the note provided above this definition in `pydevd_resolver.py` itself:

> Note: 300 is already a lot to see in the outline (after that the user should really use the shell to get things) and this also means we'll pass less information to the client side (which makes debugging faster).

Comment: I can't find pydevd_resolver.py in any of my Python VS solutions in Windows

Answer (score 5):

For the windows!

You can edit that file, `pydevd_resolver.py`, at:

```
USER_NAME\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle
```

It works for me.

Comment: What do you mean by *"For the windows"*? *"For [Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)"*? Or something else? Does "ms" in "ms-python" refer to Microsoft or not?

Comment: @PabloAriel do you know you can multiply 300 by a number?

Comment: @jriv sure. Just pointing out how bad the implementation has to be to require such a limit. I can realtime-process millions of pixels per fraction of a second with only the CPU and no hacks nor asm or other than standard language, while Python and its tools are so lame that see 300 as a reasonable limit.

Comment: Thank you for the path! I found that setting in pydevd_constants.py file in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: you can edit the `.vscode/launch.json` file and add an environment variable to increase this number like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_CONTAINER_RANDOM_ACCESS_MAX_ITEMS": "1000",
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That works and is the best solution imo. Editing the extension files seems kind of hacky and I'd assume that they would be overwritten with the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I attach VSCode to a running docker container, and I should edit the file at:

```
/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py
```

inside that docker container to make it work.

Answer (score -5):

I would advise using the debug console to manually poke and prod your data versus trying to look at all of it at once if it's that large and requires editing internal code to the debugger. The limit is there for a reason and so going past it could leave to issues.

Comment: I agree with you comment about editing internal code of the debugger. Right now I'm looking at the message 'Too large to show contents. Max items to show: 300'. There are 473 items in the list. Certainly there can be performance consequences in the UI, the debugger, IDE, etc if this limit was increased but the idea that "300" is some magic number...

Comment: The debug console also limits to 300.