# How does debugging python using VSCode shows 400 variables in watch window?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I debug Python code using VSCode, I want to entire variables in WATCH window. However, the default configuration is set to show only 300 variables. Would you tell me how to change the configuration? Below is my launch.json code.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

     {
         "name": "Launch Package",
         "type": "go",
         "request": "launch",
         "mode": "debug",         
         "dlvLoadConfig": {
             "followPointers": true,
             "maxVariableRecurse": 1,
             "maxStringLen": 400,
             "maxArrayValues": 400,
             "maxStructFields": -1
         }            
     },
     {
         "name": "Python: Current File",
         "type": "python",
         "request": "launch",
         "program": "${file}",
         "console": "integratedTerminal"
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a feature request. I've submit it to github for you. And read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330258/18359438) please. The limit is there for a reason and so going past it could leave to issues

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I couldn't enter my account.  I understand the reason why it cannot show the value. Would you tell me what do you do if you want to see the array over 300 elements?